# Update a viewepager on spinner action

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have a viewpager with  fragments, i want to update my viewpager  with new fragments once i click on an item of my spinner.
for now, whatever the spinner values are, the adapter dont update itself.
this is what i have done so far :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private ViewPager pager;
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    spinner = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.language, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    stringArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

        if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Frensh"))
        {
         pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
         pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                 invalidateOptionsMenu();
             }
         });
        }

        else if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("English"))
        {
         pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager()));
         pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                 invalidateOptionsMenu();
             }
         });

        }
        }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }
        });
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_screen_slide, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(pager.getCurrentItem() > 0);
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_next, Menu.NONE,
            (pager.getCurrentItem() == pager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1)
                    ? R.string.action_finish
                    : R.string.action_next);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.action_previous:
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_next:
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

this is the class that contains my Frensh fragments:

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        switch(pos) {
        case 0: return Fr_FirstFragment.newInstance("Page : 1");
        case 1: return Fr_SecondFragment.newInstance("Page : 2");
        case 2: return Fr_ThirdFragment.newInstance("Page : 3");
        case 3: return Fr_FourthFragment.newInstance("Page : 4");
        default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }         
}
```

this is the class that contains my english fragments:

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter2 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        switch(pos) {
        case 0: return En_FirstFragment.newInstance("Page : 1");
        case 1: return En_SecondFragment.newInstance("Page : 2");
        case 2: return En_ThirdFragment.newInstance("Page : 3");
        case 3: return En_FourthFragment.newInstance("Page : 4");
        default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }      
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm the code the block where you click on spinner item actually works ? is pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())); called ?

Comment: yes i think it works. it charges the fragments without problemes.

Comment: Do you think or It really works. Because the code which updates the ViewPager seems fine. Can you Log that spinner OnItemSelected Listener to be sure it's not the problem. It doesn't seems correct to me.

Comment: I think you should use parentView.getItemAtPosition(position) to get the selected Item.

Comment: iv already tried that one. no results dud. i dont know whats the probléme!

Comment: do you have any other suggestions plz ? the spinner listener is not working i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overall code seems fine except one thing. Your choice of using Fragment Pager Adapter is not intended to be made for this purpose. If you want to dynamically update the Data inside the Pager and the Fragments, you should use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and the rest should be the same.

Comment: should i extend the MyPagerAdapte  with FragmentStatePagerAdapter  ?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do. Let me know once you try it.